# How to select AndroidX core version used by enableJetifier=true

Tags: android, gradle, androidx, android-jetifier

I want to use some features only present in the latest release of AndroidX core, but my project is still using `android.enableJetifier=true` and if I add an `implementation` line to `build.gradle` I get duplicate class errors.

What is the right way to specify AndroidX version when using jetifier with gradle?